# HTML and Javascript Won't Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = stylesheet href = Father.css>
<title> Very Important Company </title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've included here only the portion of my HTML that involves linking with the javascript. The javascript is in a folder called "js" that is in the same folder as the HTML document. I've tried both with and without quotation marks because often my HTML doesn't work when I reference images or links within quotation marks--although most online tutorials seem to say that one must use quotation marks.

Here's the rest of the code if you must peruse it:

```js
function main() {
  $(‘.main’).hide();
  $(‘.main’).fadeIn(1000);
}

$(document).ready(main);
$(‘.main’);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#backs {
  background: white;
}

#gecko {
  content: url (“http: //www.unixstickers.com/image/data/stickers/opensuse/Opensuse-logo-wob.sh.png”);
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 50px;
  min-width: 100%
}

.navigation {
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 800px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 47px;
  min-width: 800px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

.main {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  background-image: url(http://soupbelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/DSC_0034.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  padding-top: 90px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#backs {
  background: white;
}

#gecko {
  content: url (“http: //www.unixstickers.com/image/data/stickers/opensuse/Opensuse-logo-wob.sh.png”);
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 50px;
  min-width: 100%
}

.navigation {
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 800px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 47px;
  min-width: 800px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}

.main {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  background-image: url(http://soupbelly.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/DSC_0034.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  padding-top: 90px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel=stylesheet href=Father.css>
  <title> Very Important Company </title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=backs </div>
    <div class=header>
      <p>
        <img src=http://www.unixstickers.com/image/data/stickers/opensuse/Opensuse-logo-wob.sh.png id=g ecko>
      </p>
      <div class=navigation>
        <ul>
          <li> SHOP </li>
          <li> ABOUT US </li>
          <li> RENTALS </li>
          <li> CONTACT </li>
          <li> PARTIES </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
```

Comment: You should always use quotation marks, including the ones currently missing on the `<link>` element.  Aside from that, what's the actual problem here?  What's failing?  In what specific way does it fail?

Comment: Why do you mean? That the html page can't find the functions in "js/main.js"?

Comment: invalid HTML `<link rel=s tylesheet href=F ather.css>`

Comment: Now that you've updated the code, you have a lot of ***very*** malformed HTML.  Until you fix that, all bets are off.  You also have syntax errors in your JavaScript because you're trying to use some kind of special quote character that isn't a quote character.  Use the WC3 HTML validator to help with your HTML, use jshint.com and your browser's debugging console to help with your JavaScript, and start with some tutorials on HTML/CSS/JavaScript.  There is *much* wrong here.

Comment: You mean that your html file is in the **js** folder, along with **main.js** file?

Comment: The quote marks in your jQuery selectors are also mismatched.

Comment: also using apostrophes instead of proper quotes. Check browser console for errors

Comment: Do you have a 404 error?

Comment: @David In what way is it malformed? It all seems to work besides the linking with javascript. For some reason when I copied and pasted it into stackoverflow it added some spacing within words. Was that the problem? When I add quotation marks onto my <link> element, it doesn't work. I'm really not sure why. If my javascript is working, my main div should fade in right?

Comment: @jeepersmcface: "it all seems to work" - Except for the part where it currently doesn't work, which is what brought you here?  And yes, the code you showed before was *considerably* more malformed before you fixed it recently.  Check the W3C validator for what's wrong with the HTML.  When you add quotation marks if something "doesn't work" then we can help with that.  But don't insist on doing the wrong thing just because you couldn't do the right thing correctly.  And no, your JavaScript is not working, because it's full of syntax errors.

Comment: @David I'm sorry David, I'm not trying to be rude. I'm just saying, my HTML syntax would seem correct given that it's doing everything I want it to in terms of layout, image placement etc. and thus that part "seems to work." The only thing that doesn't seem to be working is my javascript. If you have any recommendations for me to fix my javascript or the way that my HTML interacts with it I would love some advice. I apologize for my messy initial post, StackOverflow tried to "clean it up" which only denigrated my syntax.

Comment: @Julsy the HTML file is in a separate folder with the js folder that contains main.js. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @jeepersmcface: Your HTML may "seem" correct... until you encounter a problem with it.  As long as the markup is wildly invalid, the behavior of any code on that markup is undefined.  Always start with correct markup.  (As long as you *refuse* to correct your markup, the behavior any code will be potentially undefined.  That's something you're just going to have to get used to until you want to actually fix things.)  As for the JavaScript error, that's already been pointed out here multiple times.  You're using invalid characters as quotes, which results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

How come you are noticing only the script not working. Does your stylish wet even work?
The missing "" in your style sheet link may be the reason for your script not work

It should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

Remember the quotes

Noticed your kind of quotes are not right in your script. Use These

```
$('.class') or $(".class")
```

And I just prefer you write your codes the normal way in your html by putting the quotes where they need to be and also there is no where you used the

```
.main
```

In your html code

Comment: My stylesheet only works without the quotations for some reason. But yes, it works.

Comment: There is o where you used the .main in your html and you javascript quotations are not the right ones

Answer (score -2):

What you need to do is append './' to your script src tag.

So your final file should look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = stylesheet href = Father.css>
<title> Very Important Company </title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Doing this informs your HTML code to look for the 'js' folder in your current directory.

Comment: Completely unnecessary.